# Yeoman watching HAML files, but not compiling

Tags: haml, yeoman, gruntjs

When using grunt-contrib-haml, I can get Grunt to watch for HAML changes, but nothing is generated to HTML.

What do I need to add to Gruntfile.js file to get this to occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you specified the `grunt-contrib-haml` task in the watch task to execute your haml compiler? May be you did something like this:

```
watch: {
    files : [ 'public/**/*.haml', 'public/**/*.scss', 'public/**/*.coffee' ]
    tasks : [ 'compass', 'coffee' ]
}
```

Instead of

```
watch: {
    files : [ 'public/**/*.haml', 'public/**/*.scss', 'public/**/*.coffee' ]
    tasks : [ 'haml', 'compass', 'coffee' ]
}
```

Best regards :)